# JavaScript works differently in various browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

In my ASP.NET code I have two controls:

```
 <asp:Button ID="UpLoadFile" runat="server" Text="File Selection"onclientclick="fireFileClick()" onclick="ControlHasFile" CssClass="FileSelection"   />
 <asp:FileUpload ID="UpLoadButton" runat="server"  />
```

Additionally I have a script in order to isolate the `FileUpload` button and set in use another regular button.

The Script I use is in this form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fireFileClick() {
        var objfile = Object;
        objfile = document.getElementById("<%= UpLoadButton.ClientID %>");
        objfile.click();
        }
</script>
```

The script is working just fine on Internet Explorer.

But when I'm tying to use any other explorer is not working.

That means the "selected File" is not passed to the `FileUpload` control.

Under the Chrome browser (with F12 pressed) Opens the `debugger` and what I see there surprises me allot.

Which means.

When the `debugger` is `on` and stops in a line after the `objfile.click();` then the file uploads on the `Fileupload` control and the all processes goes fine.
But when the `debugger` is off (nowhere stops) then the selected file it is not uploaded to the control.

Is someone to solve that mystery?

Comment: What "selected file"?  What is `Object` in your JavaScript function?  All that code appears to be doing is finding an element on the page and clicking that element.  Is that element not being clicked?  What is cliking that element supposed to accomplish?  What is the client-side HTML that the JavaScript is interacting with in the first place?  What is the `id` you're using to find the element?  Is that element found?  What does clicking it do?

Comment: @David  all that you ask is on my Question. And have in mind that this script it runs fine in `ie 11` but in other Browsers the `file` (which I clicked) is not load it to the `UpLoadButton`. Unless I have open the debugger in a line right after the `objfile.click();` in my script.

Comment: *"all that you ask is on my Question"* - Almost none of it is.  For starters, if you have JavaScript code which is interacting with your HTML then the *first* thing you should do is look at what that HTML is.  You're not showing that in the question, you're showing server-side ASP.NET controls.  What is the actual resulting HTML that the JavaScript uses?  Also try logging debugging information to the console.  For example: `console.log(objfile);` right after you get the element by the `id`.  When you do that, what is logged to the console?

Comment: @ David The HTML is `html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd`. After I put this `console.log(objfile);` in my script absolute nothing appears. No selected file was in the control `UpLoadButton`. But when I stop the debugger in a line after the `objfile.click();` in the script then the file is load it  to the FileUpload button.
Nothing of all these happen when I use the `ie11`

Comment: @ David I turn it to HTML 5... nothing change

Comment: The HTML in the browser is much more than just a single beginning tag.  Please **actually look** at the HTML source in your browser.  You’re explicitly *ignoring* critical information about the problem, which is an ineffective means of debugging as well as essentially refusing to *be* helped here.  As for the console, if *nothing* is logged, not even an error or “undefined” or anything of any kind, then that’s a pretty conclusive indication that the code isn’t being executed at all. If you pause the debugger in that function, what is in that variable? Does it not pause at all?

Comment: @ David If I paused in this line (after the click) then the file is there and the code is executed just fine. The problem begins when the code is executed without debugger.

Comment: This is conflicting information, and suggests there’s something wrong with your debugging.  If a console.log statement is there and nothing is being logged to the console then the code isn’t executing.  You may have a problem elsewhere that you’re assuming is here.  You’re going to have to produce a minimal and complete example to demonstrate the problem.  Otherwise, combined with the fact that you won’t even look at the page HTML, we can only assume you’re making a mistake in your debugging and testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187075/discussion-between-lefteris-gkinis-and-david).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...   it looks like "various browsers - various behavior".
But the solution found it in my answer [how to assign values from Java script to a Property in a system class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347434/how-to-assign-values-from-java-script-to-a-property-in-a-system-class.<br/)

Thank all for your assistance.