# how to assign values from Java script to a Property in a system class

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a Java Script where I produce some values

```
    productionHandler._SelFileAttributes.Add(fullPath);
productionHandler._SelFileAttributes.Add(objfile.files[0].name);
productionHandler._SelFileAttributes.Add(objfile.files[0].size);
productionHandler._SelFileAttributes.Add(objfile.files[0].type);
```

I also have a Class where I have a Property

```
Public Property _SelFileAttributes As ArrayList
Get
    Return SelFileAttributes
End Get
 Set(value As ArrayList)
    SelFileAttributes = value
 End Set
End Property
```

What I want is to send the values from Java Script to the property in the Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'm clicking the hidden `upload` button control which needs to be as `<asp:FileUpload...` 
Using Java script (always) I get the value of this hidden control.
And passed in the value of another hidden button like that.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="AddAttrib" Value=""  OnValueChanged="AddAttrib_ValueChanged" />
```

As we can see by using the `OnValueChanged` event I capture it in the code behind.
From there all it is very easy 
Thank all